# Read and draw longitude and latitude data in 2 colunns

Tags: string, vb.net, text-files, gis, text-parsing

I am new to VB.NET and trying to develop a GIS system. There is a txt file like this.

[image: the data file]

I want to read the longitude and latitude, but I don't  know how to read them into two different arrays. Also, there is "# -b" line in the file, I don't know how to skip these lines.
I use code like this, but it doesn't work.

```
FileOpen(1, "coastline.dat", OpenMode.Input)
            Input(1, longtitude)
            Do While Not EOF(1)
                Input(1, latitude)
                longtitude = latitude = ""
                Do Until longtitude = "#" Or EOF(1)
                    i = 0
                    Input(1, longtitude)
                    Input(1, latitude)
                    x(i) = (Val(longtitude) + 180) * Me.Width / 360
                    y(i) = (90 - Val(latitude)) * Me.Height / 180
                    i = i + 1
                Loop
                count = i - 1
                For i = 0 To count
                    map.DrawLine(pen1, x(i), y(i), x(i + 1), y(i + 1))
                Next i
            Loop
            FileClose()
```

Comment: Please don't post images of your file. We want the actual text that we can copy/paste into a sample.

Answer (score 0):

The old `EOF`, `FileClose`, `Input`, etc functions are a legacy from old, old VB (like, the original VB) - I don't recommend using them today.

I think your code wants to read the file line-by-line and then paint a line after each input line is read. Your code should not do this because you're mixing concerns (file IO, and drawing to the screen). This also means your application will need to re-read the file every time it needs to repaint the map (assuming you're painting directly to the window rather than a `Bitmap` surface).

I suggest you first read the file into memory (i.e. RAM, program variables) as a `List(Of T)` object, and then paint the map afterwards.

First, you'll need to define a custom complex (non-scalar) data-type called a `Structure` that represents each record in the file - in this case each record is a tuple of Latitude and Longtitude represented as precise decimal numbers (not imprecise floating-point numbers), so you should use `Decimal` instead of `Single` or `Double` (as `Decimal` is a precise type, `Single` and `Double` are not).

```
Public Structure LatLong
    Public Lat As Decimal
    Public Lng As Decimal
End Structure
```

Then we need to read it in. As I said earlier, I don't recommend using the old file IO API, instead you should use `FileStream` and `StreamReader`, like so:

```
Dim list As New List(Of LatLong)

Using fs As New FileStream( "coastline.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read )
    Using reader As New StreamReader( fs )

        Dim line As String
        Do
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            If line = Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            If line.StartsWith("#") Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( line ) Then
                Continue
            End If

            Dim fields() As String
            fields = line.Split( Nothing, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )
            If fields.Length = 2 Then

                Dim lat As Decimal
                Dim lng As Decimal
                If Decimal.TryParse( fields(0), lat ) AndAlso Decimal.TryParse( fields(1), lng ) Then
                    Dim ll As New LatLong
                    ll.Lat = lat
                    ll.Lng = lng

                    list.Add( ll )
                End If

            End If

        Loop

    End Using
End Using

' Then paint them (put this in a separate function):

For i As Integer = 0 To list.Count - 2
    Dim ll0, ll1 As LatLong
    ll0 = list(i)
    ll1 = list(i + 1)

    Dim x0, x1, y0, y1 As Integer

    x0 = ( ( ll0.Lng + 180 ) * Me.Width ) / 360
    y0 = ( ( 90 - ll0.Lat ) * Me.Height ) / 180

    x1 = ( ( ll1.Lng + 180 ) * Me.Width ) / 360
    y1 = ( ( 90 - ll1.Lat ) * Me.Height ) / 180

    map.DrawLine( pen1, x0, y0, x1, y1 )

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

For dealing with the `# -b` lines, the hash (`#`) character is used as a comment marker in many text file formats. Ignore lines where the first non-whitespace character is a hash, and ignore blank lines.

That out of the way, lets get to some code. First, make a class to hold the data:

```
Public Class GeoLocation
    Public Property Latitude As Double
    Public Property Longitude As Double   

    Public Shared Function Parse(input As String) As GeoLocation
        Dim ms = Matcher.Matches(input)
        If ms.Count = 2 then
            Return New GeoLocation With {.Latitude = Double.Parse(ms(0).Groups(0).Value), .Longitude = Double.Parse(ms(1).Groups(0).Value)}
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Private Shared Matcher As New RegEx("(-?\d{1,3}[.]\d{6})")
End Class
```

Now you can use that class to help read the file:

```
Public Function ReadCoastlineData(fileName As String) As IEnumerable(Of GeoLocation)
    Return File.ReadLines("coastline.dat").
                Select(Function(line) line.Trim()).             'Sanitize
                Where(Function(line) Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(line) AndAlso 
                           Not line.StartsWith("#"c)).          'Filter
                Select(Function(line) GeoLocation.Parse(line))  'Parse                  
End Function
```

Then, the existing code can call the method and use it to draw the map like this:

```
Dim first As Boolean = True
Dim PrevX, PrevY As Single

For Each c As GeoLocation In ReadCoastlineData("coastline.dat")
    Dim X As Single = (c.Longitude + 180) * Me.Width / 360
    Dim Y As Single = (90 - c.Latitude) * Me.Height / 180

    If Not First Then
        map.DrawLine(pen1, PrevX, PrevY, X, Y)
    End If

    First = False
    PrevX = X
    PrevY = Y
Next
```

Whatever you do, get past that ganky-old `FileInput()` and friends API. Those methods are ancient and only exist for compatibility with very old code. Newer code should use the `System.IO` APIs.